# iOS black screen

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, ios-simulator

I have a weird problem ie the app sometimes becomes black and the side menu  remains visible and the flow is random and it is highly intermittent.

As crash is not happening not able to get the crash logs from the phone

The chances of happening in the simulator are very very less.
Once it happened in the simulator but couldnt figure out the correct file name(i was using view debug hierarchy to get the simulator inside xcode so that the layout can be found)

I cannot share the code for some reasons

Can anyone help me in identifying the root cause of the issue?

Comment: Very difficult to help you if you don't share any code,

Comment: just a guess: current view hierarchy does not have any views except "side menu".

Comment: I;d also guess what @abjurato said. the UIWindow is empty. Try to just change the window's background color to verify this -- OR/AND use xcode's visual debugger